# How to replace an image in website with a image in local folder

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace ’San Francisco’ image in the following picture with an image in local folder in my computer temporarily. How can I do that?

[image: Screenshot of google.com]

Comment: why you want to do that? You don't own that site

Comment: Where is the image, relative to your code/js file?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Are you just asking how to use `file://` instead of `http://`?

Comment: @David no, I want to replace an image in a website with a local image temporarily. I know after I refresh the page it will revert back to old actual image. But I like to know whether there is a way to do this temporarily?

Comment: @SureshMadhusanka: And you specifically want to do this *without* using the `file://` protocol?  Why?  Did you *try* replacing that URL with a `file://` URL in your browser's tools?  Did something not work?  What did you try?  What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Using chrome, you should be able to reference an image using `file://path/to/file`. If this doesn't work, let me know that I'm wrong.